# Convergence of series of uniform random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am working of following problem. Let $\{X_n\}$ be sequence of independent random variables, $X_n$ ~ $U[-n, n]$. For what values of $p>0$ series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n^p}$$ is convergent? Let $Y_n = \frac{X_n}{n^p}$. We have that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ and $VarX_n = \frac{n^2}{3}$, so $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = 0$ and $VarY_n = \frac{1}{3n^{2p-2}}$. From independence of $\{X_n\}$, independece of $\{Y_n\}$ follows. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = 0$.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}VarY_n  < \infty$ if and only if $p > \frac{3}{2}$, so by Kolmogorov two series theorem, sum converges a.e for  $p > \frac{3}{2}$. How can I determine convergence if $p \in (0, \frac{3}{2})$?

Answer (score 1):

If $0<p\leqslant 1$, then $\mathbb P(\lvert X_n\rvert >n^p/2)$ converges to a positive value hence the Borel-Cantelli lemma shows that the series cannot converge.

If $1<p\leqslant 3/2$, then   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(\lvert X_n\rvert >n^p )$ converges because $\lvert X_n\rvert\leqslant n$. Moreover, $X_n$ is centered hence the series converges if and only if
$$
\tag{*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{X_n}{n^p}\right)^2\mathbf{1}\left\{\left\lvert \frac{X_n}{n^p}\right\rvert \leqslant 1\right\}\right]<\infty.
$$
Using the fact that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $nU$, where $U$ is uniform on $[-1,1]$, (*) is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2-2p}\mathbb E\left[  U^2\mathbf{1}\left\{\left\lvert U\right\rvert \leqslant n^{p-1}\right\}\right]<\infty.
$$
and $\mathbb E\left[  U^2\mathbf{1}\left\{\left\lvert U\right\rvert \leqslant n^{p-1}\right\}\right]\sim \mathbb E\left[U^2\right]$, hence the divergence of the series.

Comment: For $p\ge 1$, the terms are bounded, so the two-series theorem becomes a criterion.